# Comparing strings using > in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What argument is considered in this scenario?

```
a = "ABba"
b = "abBA"
if(a<b):
    print("a<b")
elif(a==b):
    print("a=b")
elif(a>b):
    print("a>b")
```

Which gives:

```
a<b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its using Lexicographical order http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score 0):

`"A"`, character 65, is less than `"a"`, character 97, because 65 < 97. The comparison of the two strings need not progress beyond the first character.

If you wish a case-insensitive comparison, convert them to a consistent case first:

```
if a.upper() < b.upper():
    # etc.
```